# Bootstrap - cannot allign Button with Text Box vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, textbox, navbar

Im pretty new to bootstrap, how can i allign my search button with the text box in my navbar? I've tried a couple of hours now without luck. This is how it looks like:

http://bildr.no/image/TDhPNWZZ.jpeg

And this is my code:

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    <form class="navbar-form" role="search" method="get" id="search-form" name="search-form">
      <div class="input-group">

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Product", FormMethod.Get)) {
        <div class="input-group">
          @Html.TextBox("searchString", null, new { id = "txtSearch", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Søk etter vare..." })
        </div>
        }
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-success pull-left" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

EDIT: Rendered code:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Alkohol Mekka</a>

      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
          <form class="navbar-form">
            <div class="input-group">
              <form action="/Product/Search" method="get">
                <input class="form-control" id="txtSearch" name="searchString" placeholder="Søk etter vare..." type="text" value="" />
              </form>
              <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-success pull-left" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="/Customer/Register">Registrer</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/Customer/LogIn">Logg Inn</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at input groups: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

Answer (score 0):

You have an incorrect build of nested input-group class. So you have this:

```
<form class="navbar-form" role="search" method="get" id="search-form" name="search-form">
      <div class="input-group">!-- it starts here -->

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Product", FormMethod.Get)) {
        <div class="input-group">
          @Html.TextBox("searchString", null, new { id = "txtSearch", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Søk etter vare..." })
        </div>
        }
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-success pull-left" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div><!-- and ends here -->
    </form>
```

when you should have something like this:

```
<form class="navbar-form" role="search" method="get" id="search-form" name="search-form">
      <div class="input-group">

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Product", FormMethod.Get)) {

          @Html.TextBox("searchString", null, new { id = "txtSearch", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Søk etter vare..." })

        }
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-success pull-left" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Basically, you need to remove one `.input-group` class, and have the whole form (included button) inside the outer `input-group`

EDIT: Since there's a chance your unrendered code has issues ( I really don't know) here's a [**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/XuG9EkeCEi) to show you how it works with just default html markup

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I really appriciate it - but unfortunately it didn't work. I tried the one from your post, and the one from Bootply into my code, and it still looks the same..

Comment: as you can see, the Bootply works, so there's a chance your code is the culprit as well, hence why I added that edit. Can you add the rendered code so we can see what you have?

Comment: Thanks. I've posted what I think you mean by rendered code in the question now.

Comment: OK, it was really easy: you have a form tag inside the form. Just remove that and it will work. And yes, that code you're adding is the culprit, the Html.Beginform is opening that form tag inside your form, so try to remove it or add it in a way that it can handle the full BS classes (hence remove the outer form) :)

Comment: Sweet. How can i remove it and still perform the action "Search"? I am sorry but I am really new to this.. If i remove the outer form the button appears underneath the textbox.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know your code, so you'll need to figure it out, but I assume it will be more or less the same you did at @Html.TextBox since I see you can change classes, ID and such

Comment: I tried with @Url.Action("Search", "Product"); But that won't perform the Search method, I'll just add the searchString to the url.

Comment: Now the search function doesn't work.. "?searchString=txtwroteintextbox" just appears after the URL, instead of "Search/?searchString=txtwroteintextbox". Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: as I told you, I don't know your code language, I can help you with the Bootstrap and CSS part, but that language will be on your side

Comment: I figured it out. Shows that the btn-success has a built-in margin-top: 12px. More people have had problems with this. I put a margin-top: 12px to the textbox so now they align well. May be bad practice, but at least now it looks good. Anyway, thanks for you taking so much of your time trying to help me. @Fabio